# Change handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am completely new to JQuery and am having trouble getting a simple HTML page containing JQuery (that I gleaned from another Stack Overflow thread, which unfortunately wasn't complete enough for a JQuery newbie like me, apparently!) to work properly. 
When I choose a filename, I expect the "mytext" text input field to contain the name of the file I uploaded, but this does not happen.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myfile').bind('change', function() {
    var fileName = '';
    fileName = $(this).val();
    $('#mytext').html(fileName);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext">
  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
</form>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: Adding the missing `</script>` made it work. I vote to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: Also change `bind` to `on` since bind is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: And change `.html(fileName)` to `.val(fileName)` Yours does work in some browsers, but val is the preferred use for fields

Comment: @mplungjan you are correct that is what my answer does so why down vote? i do not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you were missing a /script on the jQuery tag
2. You were using .html() instead of .val() for the field
3. You should use `.on` instead of `.bind`

```js
$('#myfile').on('change', function() {
        fileName = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
        $('#mytext').val(fileName);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext">
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
```

Comment: Bind is deprecated. His code works - just missing a </script>

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please check now it works and the OP was using .html() to set the value of the input box rather than .val()

Comment: That was not the main issue. The main issue was the missing `</script>` on the jquery

Comment: But i also think that val() is more appropriate to use than html(). We should encourage to use val() for inputs rather than html()

Comment: I appreciate it